# ROR - rails - rspec - factory_girl should_not not working (as expected)

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

The thing is I'm expecting the 2-nd `it` to fail and the 3-rd to pass, but the opposite is going on. 2 is passing and 3 is failing. Does someon know why ?

spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  it 'has a valid factory' do
    FactoryGirl.create(:user).should be_valid
  end
  it 'is invalid with empty email1' do
    # I've also tried
    # FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: nil, validation_scenario: 'create').should be_valid
    FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: nil).should be_valid
  end
  it 'is invalid with empty email2' do
    FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: nil).should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

spec/factories/user.rb

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    u.email                 { Faker::Internet.email }
    u.password              'password'
    u.password_confirmation 'password'
  end
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password, :validation_scenario

  # validate on user create/update
  with_options if: -> user { ['create', 'update'].include? user.validation_scenario } do |user|
    user.validates_confirmation_of :password
    user.validates_presence_of :password, :on => :before_create
    user.validates_presence_of :email, :password
    user.validates_uniqueness_of :email
    user.validates_format_of :email, :with =>/.+@.+\..+/i
  end

  # validate on resend email cofirmation/reset password
  with_options if: -> user { ['send_email_confirmation', 'reset_password'].include? user.validation_scenario } do |user|
    user.validates_presence_of :email
    user.validates_format_of :email, :with =>/.+@.+\..+/i
  end
  ...
```

controllers/user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.validation_scenario = 'create'

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

I'm following this tutorial here:
http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/19/testing-series-rspec-models-factory-girl.html

ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]

Rails 4.0.2

Comment: How is `user.validation_scenario` set?

Comment: in the controller action (manually). but i've also tried to set it in the test file `spec/models/user_spec.rb`

Comment: Can you share that code?

Comment: I can share the code if you want to see how it's implemented, but it doesn't have anything to do with `unit tests`. I've solved it thanks to you :) (thanks) I added a new field in `spec/factories/user.rb` after the password confirmation: `u.validation_scenario   'create'`
and it works like a charm.

Comment: Seems to me you are not calling your custom validation at all.

Comment: Did you mean you added `u.validation_scenario = 'create'`? Where did you add the code?

Answer (score 0):

The thing was that i was not setting `validation_scenario` anywhere. so now:

spec/factories/user.rb looks like this:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    u.email                 { Faker::Internet.email }
    u.password              'password'
    u.password_confirmation 'password'
  end

  factory :create_user, parent: :user do |u|
    u.validation_scenario   'create'
  end
end
```

and spec/model/user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  it 'has a valid factory' do
    FactoryGirl.create(:create_user).should be_valid
  end
  it 'is invalid with empty email' do
    FactoryGirl.build(:create_user, email: nil).should_not be_valid
  end
  it 'is invalid with empty password' do
    FactoryGirl.build(:create_user, password: nil).should_not be_valid
  end
  it 'is invalid with empty password_confirmation' do
    FactoryGirl.build(:create_user, password: nil).should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

works like a charm